# Is Linq data context automatically enlisted in TransactionScope Transaction?

Tags: c#, linq, datacontext, transactionscope

I have my code something like this:

```
 using (Datacontext dc = new Datacontext(connString))
 {
     using (TransactionScope t = new TransactionScope())
     {
       //make my changes.
       //dc.submitchanges();
       // t.complete();
       // Is my datacontext automatically enlisted in the transaction scope??
     }
 }
```

Is my datacontext automatically enlisted in the transaction scope??

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386995%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that is the case.

Comment: Any particular reason that you couldn't test that for yourself?